# Discard email in Outlook 2011

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, keybindings

Say I start a new email, and I decide to discard it. If I press <kbd>Alt+W</kbd>, a window prompts me with the following three options shown below:

[image]

Most of the time I want to "Discard Changes", **but** OS X does not let me use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to change my selection.

I have tried every key combination, but and the only thing that works is using the mouse to click on "Discard Changes".

I  would like to use my keyboard to confirm that yes , I just want to discard my email. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this completely from the keyboard, go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts and enable Full Keyboard Access to All Controls, or press ⌃F7.

[image: All controls]

You can then ⇥ between the buttons, and space to select.
↩︎ will always select the default button (in this case, Save).

[image: Tabbing between buttons]